# How do I change the JDK that my Eclipse (OS X) is running on?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to get my Eclipse on OS X to start up using JDK 1.6 rather than the JDK 1.5 that it normally uses. I have edited my `eclipse.ini` file (Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini) to the following:

```
    -startup
    ../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
    --launcher.library
    ../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.100.v20110502
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vm
    /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java
    -vmargs
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx384m
    -Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
    -XstartOnFirstThread
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

but when I start up Eclipse and go to *About Eclipse SDK* → *Installation Details* → *Configuration* it still says (among other things)

```
    java.endorsed.dirs=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/endorsed
    java.home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home
    java.runtime.name=Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition
    java.runtime.version=1.5.0_30-b03-389-9M3425
    java.specification.version=1.5
    java.version=1.5.0_30
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.
        java.vm.version=1.5.0_30-161

Comment: Update: I tried running Eclipse directly from the command line: `eclipse -vm /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` and got the same result...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the -vm setting must be the first two lines of the eclipse.ini file.